# Change backcolor of DataGridViewButtonCell

Tags: vb.net

I've created a `DataGridViewButtonCell` in this way:

```
For i As Integer = 0 To dgvHouse.Rows.Count - 1
            dgvHouse.Rows(i).Cells(3) = New DataGridViewButtonCell()
End For
```

Now I want to change backcolor of these `DataGridViewButtonCell`.
I've tried to do this in the following way:

```
dgvHouse.Rows(i).Cells(3).Style.BackColor = Color.Red
```

But this change backcolor of cell not of the `DataGridViewButtonCell`

How can I do that? How can I access to a specific `DataGridViewButtonCell`

Answer (score 0):

*"But this change backcolor of cell not of the `DataGridViewButtonCell`"*. That's actually a nonsensical statement. *"the cell"* is a `DataGridViewButtonCell` and that code changes the background colour of it. The problem is that you can't see the background of the cell because it has a rendering of a button over it. That rendering is based on system settings. You'll find that you can see the background colour if you change the `FlatStyle` property to certain values. If that result isn't enough, you'll need to create a custom column with custom cells that render the way you want.

Note that, if you want something to affect every cell in the column, make the change on the column, via the `DefaultCellStyle` property.

Comment: Okay. How can I change the `FlatStyle` property?

Comment: Like I told you in my answer.

Comment: I did this: `dgvHouse.Rows(i).Cells(3).Style = FlatStyle.Flat` but error came out "`Impossible to convert value of type 'System.Windows.Forms.FlatStyle' in 'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellStyle`"